# FindBugs/SpotBugs: Filters: DTO or XML Schema

Tags: xml, findbugs, spotbugs

**In short**: Is there an official DTD or XML Schema for FindBugs/SpotBugs Filter Files?

**In detail**:
In FindBugs/SpotBugs it is possible to define filter files which are XML files.
My IDE is complaining about the missing DTD or XML Schema which is fine.
I know how to suppress this warning but I prefer adding a proper grammar file.
Therefore, is there a DTD or XML Schema provided by FindBugs/SpotBugs Filter Files?
I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update due to findbugs project being continued as spotbugs:

The current version of the xsd is located at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/3.1.0/spotbugs/etc/findbugsfilter.xsd.

And the valid namespace definition in the filter xml looks like this:

```
<FindBugsFilter
          xmlns="https://github.com/spotbugs/filter/3.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://github.com/spotbugs/filter/3.0.0 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/3.1.0/spotbugs/etc/findbugsfilter.xsd">
```

Source: https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html#complete-example

Answer (score 3):

> UPDATE: See the answer from @dpr. **SpotBugs** XSD should be use for modern projects: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/release-3.1/spotbugs/etc/findbugsfilter.xsd.

You can find the [XSD file (findbugsfilter.xsd) on the GitHub project](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/blob/master/findbugs/etc/findbugsfilter.xsd) to validate your filter configuration.

If your IDE requires an absolute URL, you can use the following :
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/master/findbugs/etc/findbugsfilter.xsd

Comment: See dpr answer. This answer is no longer valid. The xsd is no longer maintained.